# Defining the scheme $GL_1(A)$. Algebras possess norms? How is the dual algebra defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $F$ be a field and let $A$ be a unital associative $F$-algebra of dimension $n$. My notes define the group scheme $GL_1(A)$ to be the corepresentable functor $h^A$ corepresented by the hopf-algebra $S(A^*)[1/N]$ where $N:A\to F$ is the norm map considered as an element of $S^n(A^*)$.

I have two questions. Firstly, what is $A^*$ for an algebra? They just mean to consider $A$ as a $F$-vector space, and consequently they take the standard dual-space for this vector space. Secondly, does every unital associative $F$-algebra of dimension $n$ possess a norm? I know of norms arising in the context of composition algebras, like $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{d})$ for $d$ square-free, or the quaternions etc, but how does this arise in general?

Comment: $A$ acts by left multiplication on $A \cong F^n$ obtaining an embedding in $M_n(F)$, the norm is the $\det$ of the obtained matrix, $N(\sum_j x_j b_j)$ is a polynomial in the $x_j$ and $a \in A$ is inversible iff $N(a) \ne 0$

Comment: In this context $A^*$ means the units of $A$, namely, the invertible elements.

Comment: Sorry, the units of $A$ is actually the grouo. $A^*$ is the usual dual, so $S(A^*)$ is the symmetric algebra on it, and you get  in that way a coordinate free versión of the polynomial functions on the vector space $A$. But you want only the units, so you distinguishbthen as the elements acting on $A$ by invertible linear maps. That's why you invert the determinant function.